# Shortcuts from Android Studio side-effect on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> as a side-effect it changes the language in the system and when I proceed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> it activates CapsLock. On my second machine with Ubuntu 16.04 everything works as expected without collision. Should I file a bug, if so then where?